# Flutter camera plugin: how can I check that device has a flash?

Tags: flutter, camera

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/camera.

When I am setting flash mode with:
`_controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);`.

I am getting an error:
`CameraException(setFlashModeFailed, Device does not have flash capabilities)`

How can I check that device has a flash?

Comment: Can't you just catch the error and ignore?

Answer (score 0):

you have Solution
you can download package torch light and it contain function check has torch

[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/torch_light)

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to try to configure the flash depending on the Platform. An additional: if you also need to run on the web, wrap it in a try/catch block, otherwise there will be an exception when using Platform.

```
try {
  if (!Platform.isLinux && !Platform.isMacOS && !Platform.isWindows) {
    camCtrl?.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
  }
} catch (e) {
  //empty
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What about handheld devices that don't have flash, such as many iPads?